# UIKit - UINavigationController : UIViewController properties subclass or protocol?

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand relationship between UINavigationController and UIViewController.
According to apple documentation

> A container view controller that defines a stack-based scheme for navigating hierarchical content.

When I open UIKit and UINavigationController class there are some properties which I could not imagine, how they is written by Apple.

UINavigationController : UIViewController { }

so UINavigationController subclass of the UIViewController and inherit its properties.

then what about these properties in this extension ? These ones inherits from a protocol which I could not see in UIKit. Could you explain a little bit please ?

```
extension UIViewController {

    
    open var navigationItem: UINavigationItem { get } // Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its navigation appearance.

    open var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool // If YES, then when this view controller is pushed into a controller hierarchy with a bottom bar (like a tab bar), the bottom bar will slide out. Default is NO.

    open var navigationController: UINavigationController? { get } // If this view controller has been pushed onto a navigation controller, return it.
}
```

Comment: can you explain more what about those properties ? they're clearly defined in a ViewController, or your question is why they're there ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need to understand but i will assume that it's why those properties are there and exposed for the `UINavigationController`.

As the definition address it `UINavigationController` is a basically a stack of `UIViewControllers`, that uses, `push`, `pop` functions to add and remove to the stack here is more about how [stack](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/9523/stack) works.

for the relationship, it's clear that's every `UINavigationController` is inheriting a `UIViewController` but it's tricky because you are thinking why? since it hold a `UIViewController` why it inherits from it the answer rely on the usage this allows us to have multiple navigations embedded in each others so a navigation controller can hold another navigation controller inside of it, that's why you see those properties so in a scenario you can have the following stack and those properties are there if you need to use them on the `UINavigationController` it self as it gets pushed.

```
let firstVC = UIViewController()
let secondVC = UIViewController()

let firstNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
let secondNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        
firstNav.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

let thirdNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstNav)
thirdNav.pushViewController(secondNav, animated: false)
```